# Rails time zone selector: intelligently selecting a default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When signing up for an account on one of my apps, we need to store the time zone is in. We're using the time zone selector, which is fine, but I'd like to set the default value to something that it likely the user's current time zone.

Is there an easy way, either on the server or using JavaScript, to set the time zone selector to the time zone the user is currently in?

Comment: Spreedly appears to be doing exactly this, but I can't see from their scripts how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page load, get the browser's offset from GMT, and use this to pre-select the time zone selector.

```
var offestFromGMT = - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the values that the Rails TZ selector provide look like this: <option value="Eastern Time (US & Canada)">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)</option> ... so I think I need a way to convert that offsetFromGMT to the proper option value?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to write some JS to take the "-5" or "-8" and turn it into the format "-05:00", then walk the `options`, marking the first one that matches as `selected`. I think doing it in JS is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the UTC offset using data such as those from [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude-zipcode-timezone.aspx) which are based on the IP address of the user. With that you should be able to easily accomplish what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding might be better than nothing, but you have to be careful, because often the geocoding will tell you where the ISP is, but not where the actual user is.  getTimezoneOffset() is more effective since it uses the browser TZ, not the ISP TZ.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, there is no HTTP header for a users timezone or a users current time.

The best way to deal with this use case, in my opinion, is to use ip address geocoding on the server side and then translate this to a timezone using a service like [ip2address](http://www.ip2location.com/).

This does mean if the geocoding and timezone resolution is slow serving the request will be slow too.

I would also allow for customization as well because the service can not be 100% relied upon (users might be vpning to your site through their company firewall). Also, I would only do this resolution once and then store the results in a cookie.